# Create a new XDocument from an existing XDocument

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a function which takes as an argument an XDocument object.

I need to loop through a number of other objects in a different collection and for each one of those objects, perform some actions on the XDocument. But each iteration of the lopp needs a pristine copy of the original XDocument that's passed to the function.

However if I just try and perform my operations on the variable that's passed into the function it behaves like a pointer - so each iteration of the loop receives the XDocument in whatever state it was left at the end of the last iteration which is no use at all.

Obviously I need to make a copy of the Xdocument but I can see no straightforward way of doing this. Trying:

```
 XDocument currentServerXml = XDocumentFromFunction.Document():
```

And then using currentServerXml instead of XDocumentFromFunction gets me the same copy with the same pointer and the same behaviour.

How can I create a brand new copy of the data for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Did you also consider cloning your XDocument like I suggested?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for the XDocument [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341301.aspx) that takes an XDocument. This will create a deep copy of the passed XDocument.

Sample code:

```
var foo_original = XDocument.Load("foo.xml");
var foo_copy1 = new XDocument(foo_original);
var foo_copy2 = new XDocument(foo_original);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the XDocument to a stream and load another instance from that stream.

EDIT: You can implement an extension method "CreateCopy()" which may encapsulate that solution, so you can have your easy-to-use solution that you're requesting.

Comment: I don't have an overload method for XDocument that accepts a stream.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it's not a lot of help if I can't save the XDocument to a stream! I don't understand why I'm not seeing an overload for .Save that accepts a stream - am I missing a namespace or something?

Comment: I've checked that and XDocument has Save(Stream) overload! :D Here you've the overload list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save.aspx Let me know if you could use it!

Comment: Yes I checked MSDN too, but for whatever reason that overload isn't available to me. I solved it by using a textReader instead - thanks for trying.

Comment: Well, I was suggesting you "Stream", but you could use XmlWriter or whatever other overload :) It's just the idea of saving XDocument in memory and load the resulting XML in another XDocument instance. Nice to know you got the solution! BTW, I've opened my VS2010 and I created an instance of XDocument, and it has the Stream overload!! Maybe you're in .NET 3.5??

Comment: This 'feels' slower than using Dono's approach. When an XDocument reads from a Stream, it knows nothing about what it will receive. When an XDocument is created from another instance, I imagine there are optimisations that XDocument can make.

Comment: @PhilWhittington Yeah, you should be right. I guess using Dono's approach XDocument should simply set the data structure to the new instance, and that's all, while stream source should mean that the XDocument object graph might be built from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

A stream would be the best option as the other respondant suggested. However for anyone stuck in my position of not being able to use a stream, the simplest method is to use a TextReader instead:

```
            TextReader tr = new StringReader(myXDocument.ToString());
            XDocument copyOfMyXDocument = XDocument.Load(tr);
```

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

How about `MemberwiseClone` ?

```
XDocument newdoc = XDocumentFromFunction.Document().MemberwiseClone();
```